# Click materializecss card reveal button via js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
      <img class="activator" src="images/office.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
      <p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-reveal">
      <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is the code for materializecss card. The card reveal will close on clicking `<span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>` I want to auto click this via JS. I have tried .click() and .trigger('click'); i am not able to achieve it.

Comment: Auto click.Its will trigger at the time of window loading right?

Comment: yea i found the ans, it was working but because the elements changed, it was not clicking and the controller exits the card content div. i delayed it using setTimeout and was able to achieve it!

Comment: @vaibhav - can you post the code? i tried the same thing and it didn't work.